# Binding a sibling control and use it in the converter

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

Let's say I have the working code.

```
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Some text" Visibility="{Binding Text, ElementName=txt, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
  </StackPanel>
```

It binds the property of the TextBox. But now I want to bind the TextBox control itself rather than the property itself then use it in the converter. The reason is that I want to get the LineCount property of the TextBox in the converter.

Can we?

**UPDATE**

Actually the TextBox is inside a GridViewColumn.

```
<telerik:GridViewColumn>
    <telerik.GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBox....
```

Comment: Yes. just remove `Text,` . Use `{Binding ElementName=txt, Converter...}`

Comment: Just drop the property path from the Binding. However, you won't get any change notifications then. Perhaps better use a MultiBinding to Text and LineCount. The former for change notifcations, the latter for the line count.

Comment: If you want to reuse those things (say, you have many `TextBox`es you want to observe in that way), it's better to create a `Behavior` or an attached property.

Comment: See the updated please...

Answer (score 0):

The `LineCount` property changes its value not only when you change the text of the `TextBox`, but also when the layout of the `TexBox` changes (e.g. dimensions). This depends on the `TextWrapping` property of the `TextBox`.

If you want an reusable and complete solution, I would suggest you to create a `Behavior` for the `TextBox` that exposes an observable dependency property you can bind to.

Here is an example of such behavior:

```
class LineCountBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LineCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "LineCount",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(LineCountBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public int LineCount
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(LineCountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LineCountProperty, value); }
    }    

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated += LineCountChanged;
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += LineCountChanged;
    }    

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated -= LineCountChanged;
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= LineCountChanged;
    }

    private void LineCountChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LineCount = AssociatedObject.LineCount;
    }
}
```

An usage example:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
          <l:LineCountBehavior x:Name="LineCountBehavior"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding LineCount, ElementName=LineCountBehavior, Converter={StaticResource IntToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually the TextBox is inside a RadGridView Column. I am not sure if it works?